# What is the Harmless Red Cube?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I keep finding this cube in the dungeon. But I can never interact with it. Is there a purpose to it, or is it just some Easter Egg?
[image]

Comment: Hm, That's odd. I've never seen that. Is there a specific floor you usually find it on/below?

Comment: @SaintWacko Always on  the same floor. I just can't remember if it was 2nd or 3rd. =)

Comment: Third. I just ran into it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2000817), this doesn't appear to serve any purpose within the game. However, it might be a reference to one of the game's beta testers:

> I'm relatively (90%) sure it's a reference to DeadlyRedCube, an IRC regular, beta tester, and game developer who is friends with the devs of Dredmor

So it seems to just be a nod to a friend.